# localStorage and sectionStorage jQuery code

Tags: jquery, local-storage

How can I write this javaScript-Code in jQuery?

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: The question is a little strange because the localStorage functions are the same in both jQuery and vanilla js.  The only difference to your code would be the way you reference the "result" element for output.   But that's not really a localStorage issue.  Also it's "sessionStorage", not "sectionStorage". Perhaps your issue arises from this mis-spelling?

Comment: I meant what should be the Jquery codes syntax  for both line.

Comment: Tried to formulate the question in a more readable way

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML //Javascript syntax
```

Use

```
$("#result").html(localStorage.getItem("lastname")) //jQuery syntax
```

and rest of the code will be same.